# StreamCorruptedException aftet de-serialized

Tags: android, sqlite, serialization, deserialization

i'm trying to de-serialization a class from a sqlite db, this is how i serialize it:

```html
   protected String serializeRule(){
        String ruleSerialized = "";
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);
            so.writeObject(this);
            so.flush();
            ruleSerialized = bo.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ruleSerialized ="";
        }

        return ruleSerialized;
    }
```

store into a sqlite database:

```html
public void writeRule(){
        String ruleSerialized = serializeRule();
        if (ruleSerialized != null && !ruleSerialized.isEmpty() ){
            DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(RuleContract.RuleEntry.COLUMN_NAME, ruleSerialized);
            id = db.insert(RuleContract.RuleEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
    }
```

de-serialized it:

```html
 public static ArrayList<RuleBase> getRules(Context context){
        ArrayList<RuleBase> ret = new ArrayList<RuleBase>();
        DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
                RuleContract.RuleEntry._ID,
                RuleContract.RuleEntry.COLUMN_NAME
        };

        Cursor c = db.query(
                RuleContract.RuleEntry.TABLE_NAME,    // The table to query
                projection,                               // The columns to return
                null,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                                     // don't group the rows
                null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
                null                                 // The sort order
        );

        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{

                String column1 = c.getString(0);
                String column2 = c.getString(1);
                RuleBase r = getRule(column2);
                ret.add(r);
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return ret;
    }

public static RuleBase getRule(String rules){
    RuleBase obj = null;
    try {
        byte b[] = rules.getBytes();
        ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        ObjectInputStream si = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
        obj = (RuleBase) si.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return obj;
}
```

when i open a new ObjectInputStream(bi) i always have StreamCorruptedException some problem with sqlite or other?

Comment: Obviously storing ByteArrayOutputStream.toString() doesn't make sense. You should store it's byte as blob.

Comment: I agree with @Selvin. BTW, it is a propper question and donno why it was flagged!